# How can we understand acceleration direction (positive or negative)?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, time, coordinate-systems, velocity

I am studying motion in one dimension. I am having hard time to determine acceleration either positive or negative. How can I understand this?

For example in this question I thought accelaration was positive but it is negative so my answer was wrong.

```
A tennis ball is tossed upward with a speed of 3.0 m/s
​​We can ignore air resistance.
What is the velocity of the ball 0.40 s after the toss?
```

t = 0.40 s

V0 = 3.0 m/s

v= ?

a= 9.81 m/s^2 but it should be -9.81 but why?

Comment: Write out the equation for velocity given initial velocity and time and acceleration. Now think: should the velocity shortly after launch decrease or increase? There is your intuition on the sign of acceleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you fix the direction of the vertical axis, you fix the sign of the acceleration.  In your example, you chose “up” to be positive since your velocity is $+3m/s$ for the ball going up.  As gravity acts “down”, it means $g$ must be negative, i.e. $-9.8$.

The confusion occurs because in some problems it’s more convenient to define the vertical axis to point “down”.

Answer (score 0):

You should first find the force acting on the ball. It's *gravity* of course.

Now, the acceleration of the ball is in the direction of the force (or, more exactly, in the direction of the *net force*. Here's gravity is the only force). As Newton's law states: $\mathbf{F} = m\mathbf{a}$, the direction of the acceleration and the net force is same.

Now take *X*-axis to be in the upward direction, *Y*-axis to the right. The velocity is directed in the **positive X-direction** and the force is in the **negative X-direction**. Hence, the body is accelerating downwards, and it is *negative.*

Note that *negative acceleration* means *positive deceleration* and *vice-versa*.

As gravity pulls the ball toward earth, it's velocity gradually decreases to *zero* at the top position of its trajectory. That means it's facing deceleration, or negative acceleration during its upward journey, and positive acceleration in the downward journey.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what sign convection you choose, suppose you have chosen upward displacement as negative, then velocity and acceleration direction are different, hence you can take a=(+) , for basic problem  remember if direction of velocity is opposite the force like gravity then by assigning upward displacement  as positive, you can take a=(-) ,.